# Creating multi colored scatterplot in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have a pandas dataframe that has data I want to plot, but I'd like to change the color of the dot based on the sex of the animal. I've tried a bunch of different ways to get this to work. First I tried to index a dictionary based on the df column called 'Sex'

```
figure = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 6))
axes = figure.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
clr = {'M':'firebrick','F':'blueviolet', 'I':'beige'}
axes.scatter( data[ "Whole Weight"], data['Shucked Weight'],color=clr[str(data['Sex'])])
axes.set_ylabel( "Shucked Weight")
axes.set_xlabel( "Whole Weight")
axes.set_title("Whole Weight vs. Shucked Weight")

plt.show()
plt.close()
```

That gives me a bunch of key errors. Next I tried to loop through the df and add the column manually based on a row value:

```
for x1 in data['Sex']:
    if x1 == 'M':
        print(x1,)
        data['color'] = 'firebrick'
    elif x1 == 'F':
        data['color'] = 'blueviolet'
    else:
        data['color'] = 'bisque1'
```

I tried to make a dictionary from scratch that had the values in them:

```
weight_dict = pd.DataFrame(dict(whole = data['Whole Weight'], shucked = data['Shucked Weight'], sex = data['Sex'], color= some if statement that choked))
```

I tried to use the np.where statement, but I have 3 options for sex (Male, Female, and Infant, abbreviated as M,F, I)

```
data['color'] = np.where(data.Sex == 'M', 'Firebrick', (data.Sex == 'F', 'blueviolet','beige'))
```

And finally I got this to work:

```
def label_color(row):
    if row['Sex'] == 'M':
        return 'firebrick'
    elif row['Sex'] == 'F':
        return 'blueviolet'
    else:
        return 'beige'
data['color'] = data.apply(lambda row: label_color(row), axis=1)
```

but I wasn't all that satisfied with the solution. I really wanted the first solution to work where I just had a custom dictionary and looked it up during the call to axes.scatter, but the errors were just bizarre and not understandable.

Is there an easier solution to this madness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you had it almost right at the first attempt.

I'd apply the dictionary to a new column that maps sex to color. Something like

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["ww", "sw", "sex"])
df["ww"] = np.random.randn(500)
df["sw"] = np.random.randn(500)
df["sex"] = np.random.choice(["M", "F", "I"], size=500)

clr = {'M':'firebrick','F':'blueviolet', 'I':'yellow'}
df["color"] = df["sex"].apply(lambda x: clr[x])

plt.scatter(df["ww"], df["sw"], color=df["color"], alpha=0.7)
```

[image]

Or if you don't want a new column, or maybe the dictionary changes between scatter calls you can do

```
plt.scatter(df["ww"], df["sw"], color=df["sex"].apply(lambda x: clr[x]), alpha=0.7)
```

Not sure if is there a better solution using only dictionaries, but given you already have your data in pandas I'd say it's fine to use it.

Comment: Thank you sir. Very elegant, and I'm a little sad I couldn't figure out the clean way you just demonstrated.